# google places api and retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

i am trying to get from google places api list of places using there api.
i am using retrofit. the code is:
   String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/";

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ApiCalls calles = retrofit.create(ApiCalls.class);
    Call<List<Object>> call = calles.getGists("haifa",
            "<my api key>",
            "geocode", "iw");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Object>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Object>> call, Response<List<Object>> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Object>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("error", t.toString());
        }
    });
```

public interface ApiCalls {

```
@GET("json")
Call<List<Object>> getGists(@Query("input") String input, @Query("key") String key,
                            @Query("types") String types, @Query("language") String language);
```

}

the crash i am gettiing is:
06-16 18:19:46.116 826-826/? E/error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: can you post the json and ApiCalls class ?

Comment: Looks like response is not the one expected

Comment: never mind found the problem

Comment: @OriJoseph post your solution